# Why can't I activate my Django virtual environment now?

Tags: django, miniconda

I had to shut down my computer and so windows generated a new commandline terminal without my django virtual environment.  Now I can't activate my django virtual environment anymore

When I type the command "activate myDjangoEnv" it no longer takes me to my django virtual environment:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZkSC.png)

I already have Miniconda installed and I would think I need to install it again right?

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot, you seem to run the "command prompt". You should be running the "Anaconda Prompt" in order to have access to your miniconda install and all the environments you created.

The [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html) states:

```
Installing on Windows

Download the installer:
    Miniconda installer for Windows.
    Anaconda installer for Windows.

Double-click the .exe file.

Follow the instructions on the screen.

If you are unsure about any setting, accept the defaults. You can change them later.

When installation is finished, from the Start menu, open the Anaconda Prompt.

Test your installation.
```